# Why are the Neural Network Outputs not Binary?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am using the NPR tool in MATLAB. 
My inputs is a 150000 x 10 matrix and output is a class 150000 x 1 (Binary class).

I used the GUI and saved the outputs when the tool gave me an option. 
But the output is not a binary vector instead a 150000 x 1 double.

1. I just wanted to know why it isnt binary when my target variable was and if its not binary how is the confusion matrix being plot. 
   Is a simple round function being used?
2. Do I need to normalize the target variable before giving it to the NPRTool

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of the NPR Tool but neural networks are implemented as a vector multiplication with the weight vector learned during training (at each layer of the network).

The output of that is naturally a real valued vector, which (typically) to maintain generality is not thresholded. To get your predicted binary class values the output would be thresholded at 0.5 (assuming the classes are 0 and 1) and the confusion matrix computed from those. The real valued outputs also allow you to treat the output of the neural net as a kind of a confidence value as to the classification. 0.51 would be positive but not very much, whereas 0.95 would be much more positive. Like said, I don't know how exactly the NPR Tool treats these values.

As to the normalisation, I thought 0,1 is already normalised.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can set up a neural network to have a binary vector output too, if you wish, however it is perhaps redundant as you can identify two classes by output values -1,1 using only a single output variable.

So you can have either :

1) two output variables where each variable corresponds to a class or and for example (0,1) would correspond to class 1 and (1,0) to class 2.

2) one variable where the output value -1 is for class 1 and 1 denotes class 2.

In the second case you need less training points though as you have less parameters to fit.